# multiple servlet request from same jsp

Tags: image, jsp, servlets, request

I have a servlet which produces an image file. I am trying to send two different requests (with different param) from a single jsp page to show two different images. It seems the images get mixed up randomly. sometimes the page shows two different images, sometimes shows image1 in both places, sometimes shows image2 in both places. Is this expected behavior? could someone explain what could be happening? I am trying to avoid having two different servlets for each image.

Comment: Show us some code , very unlikely if the servlet was written correctly as each request will execute in its own thread.

Comment: <img class='resultareaImage' src='/WAP/chartSummaryReboot.do?date=<c:out value="${summary.date}" />&vendor=aaa'/> 
<img class='resultareaImage' src='/WAP/chartSummaryReboot.do?date=<c:out value="${summary.date}" />&vendor=bbb'/> 

public ActionForward execute(...) {  
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
...
JFreeChart chart = chartService.createBarChart(params..);
if (chart != null) {
 response.setContentType("image/png");
 response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
 ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(os, chart, 900, 300);
 response.flushBuffer();
 return null;
}

Comment: basically jsp has two img tags. and servlet produces jfreechart image file and write it into response. I have added println statement to see which requests are coming into servlet. When image files gets mixed up, I see that same request(vendor being aaa twice, not aaa and bbb) gets sent to the servlet.